# How can i convert each element in my panda dataframe from a list to a series? In order to be comapatiable with MiniRocketMultivariateVariable sktime

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, sktime

I have a dataframe. This dataframe holds ts data

Every column is a dimension in my ts data. Every  row  holds an indidual time series. Ts that i have are not eual in length.
[image: Structure of my dataframe]

I want each element in my dataframe to be converted to a series instead. Meaing that i will still have the same number of rows and same number of columns. However instead the type of each element is an array it will be pandas series

Aslo note that i am trying to change it to that structure to use MiniRocketMultivariateVariable from sktime

I tried using the apply method but no luck`df = df.applymap(pd.Series)`
I also tried to change it using pd.series by creating another column `df['col_3'] = pd.Series(df['dim_1'])` However the elements of the new column is still a list type

The ouput that i would like is a dataframw with the same number of columns and same number of rows. However each element is a pandas series instead of a list an example of the structure is below[image: desired structure]

Comment: have you tried `pd.Series(theList)`?

Comment: yeah i tried to change one elemnt to see if it will work or not.  df_series.loc[0][0] =pd.Series(df_series.loc[0][0]) but still if i check that specfic element i get an array not a sereis

Comment: Can you show how exactly you want the output?

Comment: Sure thing! i edited the post to include an example of the desired structure

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
d = {'dim_1' : [[0,1,2,3,4.34,5,6], [0.234,1,2,3,4,5,7]], 'dim_2' : [[0,1.24,2,3,3,4,5], [0,1,2,3,4.67,5,6]]}
df_series = pd.DataFrame(d)


def test(series):
     a = " ".join(f"{i}" for i in series)
     return a
    
x = df_series.applymap(test)
df_series = x
df_series
```

Output:

```
          dim_1               dim_2
0   0 1 2 3 4.34 5 6    0 1.24 2 3 3 4 5
1   0.234 1 2 3 4 5 7   0 1 2 3 4.67 5 6
```

Comment: Actually, now that i am checking it converts them to a string. I still want them to be numeric. is there a posssible way?